# Rigid Body Physics (Collisions)

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, collision

I am using Rigid Body Physics in Blender 2.83 to have some cubes fall into a bowl. It should be quite simple, but as you can see the result is grossly over-dramatic.

What am I doing wrong, or not doing?

Thanks,
Paul

[image: Frame grab]

[image]

Comment: cant really get whats wrong , can i get a pic of a larger frame covering the place where the cubes are coming from , if you have sandwiched the closely , they will collide with each other and then scatter apart

Comment: Hi,
I have added a picture of the cubes before they drop. There is air between each cube.
This might be a bug with Physics Properties > Collisions > Shape > Mesh
in Blender 2.83. The Physics works for Shape > Box, etc. just not for Mesh. When I set it up exactly the same in Blender 2.79 it all works as one would expect. I will try 2.9 to see if the bug has been sorted.
Unless you know any work-arounds????

Comment: Can you post a picture of your cube physics settings? Also, how are you generating the extra cubes?

Comment: @PaulStGeorge look at the sensitivyty and check collision margins , and set it to 0.01

Comment: Yes. I had Scene Properties > Unit System set to Metric. So, even though I was using a small number for the Margin the distance was too big.
Changing the Unit System to None did the job. I could then, as suggested, put small numbers in Margin settings and in Settings > Mass. Now it works!!
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the margin of the the cubes are too big , you need to shorten it by going to sensitivity > check collision margin and enter numbers like 0.01